# Assigning Layout in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Can we define a Layout for whole controller in that particular controller?I have used before filter of the appcontroller for this purpose earlier but it doesnt solves it any more.So i need that there should be some definition of layout in controller that would apply for all the actions of that controller.

Regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use it:

inside your action

```
$this->layout = 'mylayout';
```

you have to create that layout in view/layout/mylayout.ctp

or add this function to controller to set layout for each action of controller

```
  function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->layout = 'mylayout';
  }
```

Comment: Yes i have did this.It struck to me after posting the question thanx sukinsan.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do some thing like this

```
var $layout = 'my_account';
```

This will apply to your entire controller.
After adding this code it will look something like this.

```
class MyAccountsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'MyAccounts';
    var $components = array('Email');
    var $layout = 'my_account';
```

If you do not want to use some of the action you can explicitly define in your action like this

```
function my_action(){
    $this->layout = 'another_layout';
}
```

Now this `my_action` will take another layout and rest of the action will take `my_account` layout

Answer (score 5):

For CakePHP 3.0 Red Velvet

Layout file location:

[image]

New param:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->layout("loginUI");
```

*"loginUI" is file name layout

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can. You just need to create your layout file under Template>>Layout>>yourlayout.ctp
Then load this layout along with the Controller by:

```
class MyController extends AppController {
    public function initialize(){
        parent :: initialize();
        $this->layout = "yourlayout";

      }
}
```

this will automatically implement this layout as default for the Controller.
you might want to use $this->viewBuilder->layout("yourlayout"); inside the initialize() but it leads to error "Call to member function layout() on boolean". So instead you can use the former.